# How to Close Popup's having No Close(X) button in testRigor?

Tags: popup, testrigor

I have to click out of a popup in order to close it. Popup doesn't have any close buttons.
I have tried commands like `click above "popup"` and `click on the right edge of the screen`. But didn't help out.
Is there any commands to enter "esc" in the Screen? or other commands to click out of popup in testRigor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape command is available, just do `enter escape`